# Is the former adviser to the prime minister Dominic Cummings related by marriage to Andrew Wakefield?

Tags: political-history, united-kingdom, medicine

Is Dominic Cummings, the British prime minister's former chief adviser, related by marriage to Andrew Wakefield, director of the 2016 film "Vaxxed"?
Dominic Cummings, the former adviser to the British prime minister, is married to Mary **Wakefield**, the commissioning editor at the *Spectator*.

Andrew **Wakefield** is the British former medic who campaigns against the MMR vaccine and directed the 2016 film *Vaxxed*.

Are they related?

Comment: I did a quick check, and didn't find any direct link (without looking into removals). It also appears to be a very, very common last name. That doesn't mean there's no close relation, but it does mean internet searches for links become quite challenging.

Comment: It is also the name of an [English city](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wakefield) with a population of around 100,000

Comment: Re: your "Note": How is this about 'History'? *For our purposes:* "Famous people" ≠ "in the news", and this personal relationship angle as "political history" … is how exactly? What does this achieve if answered either way? (Crazy couples or odd relatives examples?)

Comment: It falls into the category of "Famous people" as listed in the guidance. DC is famous for Brexit and the 2019 British general election. AW is famous as a leading global critic of the MMR vaccine. Sorry but I am not interested in answering your questions, except to say that what an answer might "achieve" is that then I will know the answer. I don't know who you are quoting when you mention "political history", nor who you are referring to when you say "our". If semantic considerations make you want this question removed from the company's website, post a dislike (or "downvote").

Answer (score 3):

- A [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22Mary+Wakefield%22+%22Andrew+Wakefield%22) for **both Wakefields side by side** reveals less than a hundred results, none of them even remotely relevant; and [when the two names do indeed appear together](http://www.mananarestaurantmn.com/4lql83/wakefield-covid-vaccine-dept), it is [another Mary Wakefield altogether](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Wakefield); this would appear highly unlikely, were the two Wakefields to have indeed been related.

---

> **Mary Wakefield** has **two brothers**; **Maximilian Wakefield** (born 1967), an entrepreneur and racing car driver, and **Jack Wakefield** (born 1977), former director of the Firtash Foundation and an art critic who writes for The Spectator and other publications. A **third brother**, **William Wakefield**, was born in 1975 and **died in infancy**.
>
> In December 2011, Wakefield married **[Dominic Cummings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominic_Cummings), a friend of her brother Jack Wakefield**.

— [Mary Wakefield (journalist)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Wakefield_(journalist))

It would seem far fetched to go as far as mentioning a brother who died in infancy, and fail to mention [a by far more famous one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_Wakefield), were the two to have truly been siblings; of ocurse, they could still, in theory, be (distant) cousins, or uncle and niece (of some degree), but, with over [forty thousand people](http://www.forebears.io/surnames/wakefield) sharing this particular surname in the Anglosaxon world, it's not clear why one might expect these two, in particular, to be closer than any other such possible pairing; I myself happen to bear the same surname as one of my town's former mayors.

Comment: Thanks for this. I see those 40000 Wakefields are most prevalent in the US, whereas the two people enquired about in the question are British and in the privately-educated 7% of that country's population. So if we guess that the proportion of Wakefields who are British is 40% and assume they are evenly distributed across social classes, then the pool is cut to ~1100 people. Given that the privately-educated tend to have more than the average number of children this is tantalising, even if one cannot expect to prove that they are *not* related.

Comment: Mary Wakefield is the daughter of the baronet Humphrey Wakefield, who used to work for Christie's and is a nephew of the 1st Baron Wakefield of Kendal. Andrew Wakefield is, [according to this reviewer](https://forbetterscience.com/2020/10/13/brian-deers-book-on-andrew-wakefield-the-doctor-who-fooled-the-world/) of a highly critical book about him, shown therein as hailing "from a pedigree English family". Hmm...